# Application stops responding and give NullPointerException on changing device orientation.

Tags: java, android, logcat

My application is working fine except when i rotate device, in that case it gives `NullPointerException`.To handle screen rotation i have already overridden `onSaveInstanceState`.i checked logcat also it says `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.CheatActivity.onCreate(CheatActivity.java:42)` code at *line 42* is `mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button)`. java file as well as logcat detail are posted below.What could be the reason ? i am new to android.

*java:*

```
    public class CheatActivity extends Activity {

        public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE =
                "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_is_true";
        private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;
        private TextView mAnswerTextView;
        private Button mShowAnswer;
        public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN="om.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_shown";
        public static final String KEY_CHEATER = "cheater";
        private boolean mAnswerShown; 

        private void setAnswerShowResult(boolean isAnswerShown){
            Intent data= new Intent();
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
            mAnswerShown = isAnswerShown;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activiy_cheat);
             if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                    setAnswerShowResult(false);
                }
             if (savedInstanceState != null){
                 setAnswerShowResult(savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_CHEATER, false));
                 if(mAnswerIsTrue){
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
                 } else{
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
                 }
              }
            mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent()
                    .getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE,false);
            mAnswerTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);
            mShowAnswer=(Button) findViewById(R.id.showAnswerButton);
            //setAnswerShowResult(false);
            mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(mAnswerIsTrue){
                        mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
                    }else{
                        mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
                    }
                    setAnswerShowResult(true);
                }
            });

        }

         public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){

super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);           
savedInstanceState.putBoolean(KEY_CHEATER, mAnswerShown);

           }

    }
```

*LogCat:*

```
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185): Process: com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz, PID: 25185
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz/com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.CheatActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3805)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:139)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1216)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.CheatActivity.onCreate(CheatActivity.java:42)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
10-28 23:51:20.769: E/AndroidRuntime(25185):    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `setText()` on `mAnswerTextView` before you assign a value to `mAnswerTextView`. Move your `savedInstanceState` work to the end of `onCreate()`, after you have called `findViewById()` to retrieve your widgets.

Answer (score 2):

On line 42, you are trying call `setText` on `mAnswerTextView`, but it has not been initialized. (Because when you change the orientation of the device, `onCreate` is called again).

To fix this, you simply need to initialize the `TextView` before you call `setText`. Move the following line

```
mAnswerTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);
```

above where you check if `savedInstanceState` is null (as long as it's still after `setContentView`, calling it before this would cause another error)

```
if (savedInstanceState != null){
....
```

This will ensure that when the activity is first created, and whenever it's recreated, you will be able to call `setText` on your `TextView`

Comment: thanks man.My bad.it is working fine now. But why i was not getting error for the first time when activity was created ? why only after rotation i got nullpointerException ?

Comment: Because the first time, `savedInstanceState` is not null, so the code inside there doesn't get called. The other instances in `onCreate` where you call `setText` are after you initialize the `TextView`, so those work fine.